# Enable parse_ini_file into .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

anyone knows if is it possible to enable php parse_ini_file() function overriding php.ini settings into .htaccess? If yes how it can be done?

Thank you all for help

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "into .htaccess"? What are you trying to achieve? You can alter _some_ PHP settings at runtime with `ini_set`. `parse_ini_file` is for parsing arbitrary INI-format text files, not live server configuration.

Comment: There is no ini setting affecting `parse_ini_file()` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to install Joomla 1.6.1 on a free hosting and if fails because parse_ini_file is probably disabled into php.ini. Because of I can't modify php.ini i found out in some websites that some php settings can be overridden using the .htaccess file. So I am asking if it could be done and how.

Comment: Weird. As long as you cant access others' files I dont see any security or perfomance issue with `parse_ini_file()`. You can ask your hoster, if they want to change the ini for you. In my oppinion it doesnt make much sense to disable this function. Since 5.3 `parse_ini_string()` is available. You can try, if this function in conjunction with `file_get_contents()` works :) (if you have php >= 5.3 installed)

Comment: I see. I'll have a try in asking to hoster. I think other users are facing this issue. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was disabled using `disable_functions`, you can't reactivate it using a `.htaccess` `php_value` directive. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [parse_ini_file()](http://es2.php.net/parse_ini_file) is a core function built into PHP, thus it can't really be *enabled*. I'll guess that you are facing one of these situations:

1. Your host has disabled it for security reasons (:-?) using the [disable_functions](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive.
2. You are providing a URL in the `$filename` parameter and your host has disabled loading or remote files with the [allow_url_fopen](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) directive.
3. You are reading an *.ini file you don't have access to.

In general, all three cases imply that you are just not allowed to do so. Even if you manage to find a hack and override the restriction, you might be violating your host's terms of use. Whatever, it's possible that you are just trying to do the wrong thing:

- Local files can be read from disc, there is not need to use HTTP.
- You should be able to read your own files, given that they're given the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I added a copy of php.ini under the folder where application wants to call `parse_ini_file()` and it helped, but my hosting provider "honors" php.ini file per directory, so each app can use different settings.

In this case the app was complaining `PHP function parse_ini_file is not available` not because the method was disabled, but because it could not find php.ini to parse.